# How to disable Time and date settings for normal users in Ubuntu?

Tags: time

I need to disable time and date setting for standard users in Ubuntu.

How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need admin rights to change the date and time, so you need not worry non-admin users would change it unless they have the admin password :)